# Gatsby npm install fails on 5.12.8

Tags: gatsby

I tried upgrading Gatsby from 5.12.4 to 5.12.8 but it failed with the following error:

```
npm ERR! code 7
npm ERR! path /home/anton/Git/physically-based-web/node_modules/sharp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
```

I don't know what it means, other than it has something to do with "sharp", maybe?

The weird thing is that after cleaning everything out, it still fails.
I've tried everything suggested in different forums:

- gatsby clean
- Removing package-lock.json
- Reinstalling npm
- Reinstalling gatsby-cli
- Wiping the whole project and cloning it from Github again
- sudo npm install sharp --unsafe-perm